# Removing @WebServlet causes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Tomcat 7 in eclipse Juno with servlet 3.0 specs (jdk 1.7).
When I create a new servlet using Eclipse IDE it automaticaly create a new mapping using `@WebServlet("/foo")` statement and everything works fine (the servlet works).

Removing the `@WebServlet("/foo")` mapping and using the manual one in web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <servlet-path>foo.Servlet</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

causes Tomcat crash:

```
 SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

I'm sure that foo.Servlet.Servlet1 is the correct path and name.
I've to manually compile the servlet before starts Tomcat? I run the project directly from eclipse ide, setting up a Tomcat 7 Runtime Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Servlet declaration in `web.xml` is not correct, You need to change

```
<servlet-path>foo.Servlet</servlet-path>
```

with

```
<servlet-class>foo.Servlet</servlet-class>
```

Also you should add the [schema declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm) in your `web.xml` file, it would have saved you all this trouble by showing the error in your xml editor because there is nothing such as `<servlet-path>` in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```